# Android get background color of parent view if no background color set

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, textview, background-color

I have a a TextView for which I have not set a background color yet. I would like go the background color, but when I do `((ColorDrawable) mTextView.getBackground()).getColor()` I obviously get a null pointer exception.

How would I traverse the view hierarchy of the TextView to find the most recent **background color** in the hierarchy that the TextView uses as background as a result.

And **how would I determine the background color if no background color has been set in the hierarchy?** And how would I determine that situation? How can I tell that no background has been set?

I basically have difficulty to determine the background color of a view when it has not been set explicitly.

Comment: you have to first find out its position in view hierarchy. like linearlayoutl.getChildAt(index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how generally applicable this is but it does the trick for me:

```java
int getBackgroundColor(View view, int fallbackColor) {
    if (view.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        return ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor();
    } else {
        if (view.getParent() instanceof View)
            return getBackgroundColor((View) view.getParent(), fallbackColor);
        else
            return fallbackColor;
    }
}
```

It tries to cast the background as `ColorDrawable` and if that fails it tries again on its parent, recursively. If the parent is not a `View`, the specified fallback color is returned.

Now for some Kotlin poetry:

```kotlin
tailrec fun View.getBackgroundColor(): Int? =
    (background as? ColorDrawable)?.color
        ?: (parent as? View)?.getBackgroundColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse in hierarchy depends upon **what controls you have used**.

now, to get color of layout, this can only be accomplished in API 11+ if your background is a solid color.

```
            int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            Drawable background = view.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
            color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```

once you get **colorcode** you can do operations based on that.